# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed while migrate from java 6 to java8 and tomcat5.5 to tomcat8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

While migration from java6 to java8 and tomcat5.5 to tomcat8.5 i am getting this error. In older version its working fine but in newer version i am getting this error.

```java
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
out.print(projectStr);
out.flush();
```

The above code written before  return mapping.findForward(target);

```java
if(projectStr.length() > 0)
        projectStr = projectStr.substring(0,projectStr.length()-2);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        out.print(projectStr);
        out.flush();
    }
    if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("PI")){
        query = sqlprop.getKeyValue("getListProjPiaOngoing");
        pstmt.close();
        pstmt=null;
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, loginid);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            projectStr = projectStr + rs.getString("project_cd") + "##" + rs.getString("proj_name") + "$$";
        }
        if(projectStr.length() > 0)
            projectStr = projectStr.substring(0,projectStr.length()-2);
        request.setAttribute("projectStr", projectStr);
    }
    }}
    catch (Exception e) {
        target = "error";
        logger.error(currTimestamp + " : Exception in com.iwmp.master.DistRecAmtDelete homeFltr() : "+e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(pstmt!=null){
                pstmt.close();
                pstmt=null;
            }
            if (conn != null){
                ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(conn);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(currTimestamp + " Exception in Finally block of com.iwmp.master.DistRecAmtDelete homeFltr()::"+e);
            target = "error";
        }
    }
    return mapping.findForward(target);
}
```

I expect that it should redirect with the desired result as it works fine in java6 and tomcat5.5.

Comment: What is the type of mapping variable? Also, there is missing opening block "{" for if(projectStr.length() > 0) block. Error message is self explaining, response is already send back to the client in out.print(projectStr);  out.flush(); and after that you might trying to forward request to another servlet in this statement "mapping.findForward(target);". Please add more details.

Comment: @AsSiDe mapping variable is of type ActionMapping and after writing in out.print(projectStr) i am trying to forward the control to the same page from where request comes.